# Creating a RTMP server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to create an RTMP server using nodejs that takes an incoming stream and transcodes the stream to save it as an mp4. The issue that I am having is when I set the videoCodec to 'copy' it will save it as I received it, but if I change it to libx264 the video bitrate is very low. Around 200-250k even though I have set the minBitrate of 5000K.My pc is more than capable of transcoding so its not a hardware issue.

```
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';


ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('notmyrealpath');


const nms = new NodeMediaServer({
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 30,
    ping_timeout: 60,
  },
});

// FFmpeg transcoding options
const transcodeOptions = {
  videoCodec: 'libx264',
  audioCodec: 'aac',
  outputFormat: 'mp4',
  minBitrate: '5000k',
  maxBitrate: '5000k',
};

nms.on('prePublish', (id, StreamPath, args) => {
  const inputUrl = `rtmp://localhost${StreamPath}`;

  const outputFilename = `output_${Date.now()}.mp4`;

  const outputPath = `./media/${outputFilename}`;

  const command = ffmpeg(inputUrl)
    .output(outputPath)
    .videoCodec(transcodeOptions.videoCodec)
    .audioCodec(transcodeOptions.audioCodec)
    .format(transcodeOptions.outputFormat)
    .videoBitrate(transcodeOptions.maxBitrate)
    .outputOptions('-threads 8')
    .outputOptions(`-bufsize ${transcodeOptions.maxBitrate}`)
    .outputOptions('-g 50')
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('Transcoding finished.');
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('An error occurred:', err.message);
    });

  // Start transcoding
  command.run();
});

// Start the NodeMediaServer
nms.run();

``
```